# Why can I declare a str variable as mutable if Rust str is immutable?

Tags: string, rust

According to: https://web.mit.edu/rust-lang_v1.25/arch/amd64_ubuntu1404/share/doc/rust/html/book/first-edition/strings.html

rust str is immutable, and cannot be used when mutability is required.

However, the following program compiles and works

```
fn main() {
    let mut mystr = "foo";   
    mystr = "bar";    
    {
         mystr = "baz";      
    }
    println!("{:?}", mystr);  
}
```

Can someone explain the mutability of str in Rust?

I expect `let mut mystr = "foo";` to result in compilation error since str in Rust is immutable. But it compiles.

Comment: You are not mutating `str` here, you're just replacing one `&str` with another `&str`.

Comment: I've never coded rust, but doesn't `mut` only apply to the variable, not the contents? e.g. you can re-assign the variable to a different string, but you cannot change the string itself? (pretty much like `final` works in Java). Never coded rust, so I might be totally wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You did not change the string itself. `&str` is basically `(*const u8, usize)` - a pointer to the buffer and a length. While mutating a variable with type `&str`, you’re just replacing one pointer with another and *not* mutating the original buffer. Immutability of a string literal means that the buffer is actually linked to your binary (and, as I remember, is contained in `.rodata`), so you cannot change it’s contents. To actually mutate a string, use a heap-allocated one - `String`.